# how to display an image saved in my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a database where  I have saved image

[image]

How can I display the image ?
Now I display it like this

```
    <img alt="@album.Room_number" src="@album.ImageData" />
```

But I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) if your client browser supports it:

```
<img alt="@album.Room_number" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(album.ImageData)" />
```

If the browser doesn't support it you will have to create a controller action that queries the database and streams the image to the response:

```
public ActionResult Image(int id)
{
    byte[] imageData = ... go and fetch the corresponding image data from the database
    return File(imageData, "image/jpeg");
}
```

and then:

```
<img alt="@album.Room_number" src="@Url.Action("Image", new { id = album.ImageId })" />
```

Of course in this case you should not fetch the `ImageData` property within the initial request to avoid to unnecessary query it while not using it anymore in the view.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a controller action that serves the raw image data using `return File(...)`.

You can then write `<img src="@Url.Action(...)" />`.